# How can I reproduce a goreleaser run locally?

Tags: go, static-linking, goreleaser

Context: there's a [repo](https://github.com/confluentinc/terraform-provider-confluent) that uses [GoReleaser tool](https://goreleaser.com/) that compiles binaries and [releases](https://github.com/confluentinc/terraform-provider-confluent/releases) it to GitHub.

As described in [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/terraform-provider-confluent/issues/205#issuecomment-1452542382), a commit tagged `v1.32.0` resulted in a release with dynamically linked binaries -- and that's OK: for example, if you [download](https://github.com/confluentinc/terraform-provider-confluent/releases/tag/v1.32.0) the `terraform-provider-confluent_1.32.0_linux_amd64` binary and then run `file` command you'd see "dynamically linked":

```
$ file ~/MyDownloads/terraform-provider-confluent_1.32.0_linux_amd64/terraform-provider-confluent_1.32.0
/Users/klinou/MyDownloads/terraform-provider-confluent_1.32.0_linux_amd64/terraform-provider-confluent_1.32.0: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, Go BuildID=8SfNWb1Abn_y718BUN-I/PH1ZOJTKh7G-G89wQMVi/7pnMTwFFJzGpJwJM40fD/vwMzK5ZvGUHoFFCvKApk, stripped
```

I've been trying to update .goreleaser config to generate a statically linked binary. But the issue is I can't even reproduce "dynamically linked" message when running a [GoReleaser tool](https://goreleaser.com/) locally:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/confluentinc/terraform-provider-confluent.git
$ cd terraform-provider-confluent
$ git checkout v1.32.0
$ git log --pretty=oneline | head -n 2
77e1ff645b2beb7c723d72e8a3a45404a86540ab chore: minor version bump v1.32.0
8794b8e9db91abc0386463824349dbbdca406917 #minor Prepare for 1.32.0 release (#382)
$ goreleaser build
   • building...
   • loading config file       file=.goreleaser.yml
   • loading environment variables
   • getting and validating git state
      • building...               commit=77e1ff645b2beb7c723d72e8a3a45404a86540ab latest tag=v1.32.0
   • parsing tag
...
      • building                  binary=dist/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_freebsd_arm_6/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_1.32.0
      • building                  binary=dist/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_windows_arm_6/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_1.32.0.exe
      • building                  binary=dist/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_linux_arm64/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_1.32.0
      • building                  binary=dist/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_windows_arm64/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_1.32.0.exe
   • storing release metadata
      • writing                   file=dist/artifacts.json
      • writing                   file=dist/metadata.json
   • build succeeded after 185.72s
```

```
$ file dist/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_linux_amd64/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_1.32.0
dist/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_linux_amd64/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_1.32.0: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=mcIeopVb5rXUWUc_eSUS/j1Bzyx4mWzFzh_9rKrtG/KancpatKw1cE9IjTQJmA/t6Dl2Mx7-b1wnGTxHaMx, stripped
```

And in the end, I can see `statically linked` and not `dynamically linked` for `file` command. What should I fix (GoReleaser command?) to reproduce a "remote" run of a GoReleaser to see `dynamically linked`?

Update: https://github.com/zambien/terraform-provider-apigee/issues/48 seems to be relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On v1.32.0 you had a typo in `CGO_ENABLED`, so, in fact, there was no value set for it.

https://github.com/confluentinc/terraform-provider-confluent/blob/v1.32.0/.goreleaser.yml#L32

If you `go build` locally for the same OS without setting any value for `CGO_ENABLED`, the binary will be dynamically linked, and if you build for another `GOOS` (let's say, from `darwin` you set `GOOS=linux`), it'll be statically linked.

So, this has very little to do with GoReleaser per se, and more about the Go toolchain and a typo.

Answering your question, if you set `CGO_ENABLED=1` on your GoReleaser's configuration file, you should be able to reproduce it locally. I would advise to use `--skip-publish` though, as you probably don't want to be re-publishing artifacts every time.

Comment: Will it just work with `CGO_ENABLED=1` or I'll have to use additional flags specified here: https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/go-1-18-4-created-static-binary-but-go-1-19-1-binary-is-dynamic/28780/1?

Comment: why is this marked as the answer... it does nothing to address the question about goreleaser running locally.

Comment: yes it does, the problem wasn't running locally or not, was a misconfiguration of the goreleaser config file. If you read the entire question and answer, you'll realize that.

Answer (score -1):

[Seems like](https://github.com/zambien/terraform-provider-apigee/issues/48#issuecomment-554198309) it's related to golang and not so much to GoReleaser tool. I managed to reproduce it when running it `alpine:latest`:

```
/terraform-provider-confluent # GOOS=linux GOEXPERIMENT=boringcrypto GO_ENABLEDC=1 GO111MODULE=on go build -mod=vendor -o ./bin/test
/terraform-provider-confluent # file bin/test
bin/test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, Go BuildID=fhj6Ss4N5d_ykkAthq4k/V5mMr10YkNseYsALvX59/LCV_yXtocvQbKjlFWnVk/amlBkYDQQEWLeECvcQxy, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the title is

> How can I reproduce a goreleaser run locally?

The answer is:

```bash
goreleaser build --snapshot
```